# Searchview en recyclerview

Tags: firebase, kotlin, recyclerview, searchview, realtime-database

Estoy implementando una lista de busqueda que cargo en un recyclerview y a traves del searchview trato de hacer la consulta pero cuando escribo algun texto inmediatamente se detiene la aplicacion y me enseña el siguiente error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent, PID: 23482
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 148914192 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 104MB until OOM, target footprint 183670968, growth limit 268435456
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3136)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3106)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:275)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:249)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:241)
    at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:590)
    at com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.adaptadores.RecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.kt:32)
    at com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.adaptadores.RecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.kt:17)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1998)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:5434)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1048)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:858)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:789)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1033)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8333)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:603)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Cuál es el código, de otra forma es difícil saber que solución dar. revisa [ask], saludos

Comment: @Jorgesys Ya solucione. Muchas gracias.